# Binding in SwiftUI ForEach from Parent to Child

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject, swiftui-foreach

I have a `Subtask` defined like this:

```
struct Subtask: Identifiable{
  var id = UUID().uuidString
  var text = ""
}
```

I populate an array of them in an `ObservableObject` like this:

```
//View Model
class SubtaskModel: ObservableObject {
  static let shared = SubtaskModel()

  @Published var subtasks = [Subtask]()
  
  init(){
    //Code that creates the subtasks array
  }
}
```

Then I render them starting in my parent view like this:

```
//Parent View
struct ParentView: View {
  @StateObject var model = SubtaskModel.shared
  ...
  
  ForEach($model.subtasks) { subtask in
    ChildView(subtask: $subtask)
  }
}
```

With the intent of being able to modify each individual `Subtask` in the child view:

```
//Child View
struct ChildView: View{
  @Binding var subtask: Subtask
  
  ...
  TextField("Text...", text: $subtask.text, onCommit:{
    print("Save subtask!")
  })
}
```

I'm getting an error in the `ParentView` on this line:

```
ChildView(subtask: $subtask)
```

...that says:

> *Cannot find '$subtask' in scope*

So it seems the `ForEach` is not returning a binding for each of the `subtasks` returned by my view model. I have tried other variations of the `ForEach` but still get the error:

```
ForEach(model.subtasks) { subtask in
ForEach($model.subtasks, id: \.self) { subtask in
ForEach($model.subtasks, id: \.id) { subtask in
```

How can I bind a child `Subtask` from a parent to a child view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the `$` before `subtask`.

If you don't write `$subtask`, then `subtask` is now a `Binding<Subtask>`. This would mean you can still do `subtask.wrappedValue` to use `subtask` normally and `subtask` to use the binding, but that's not as neat. With the `$`, `$subtask` is a `Binding<Subtask>` and `subtask` is a `Subtask`.

Change:

```
ForEach($model.subtasks) { subtask in
    ChildView(subtask: $subtask)
}
```

To:

```
ForEach($model.subtasks) { $subtask in
    ChildView(subtask: $subtask)
}
```

Or alternatively (and more confusingly, I **don't** recommend):

```
ForEach($model.subtasks) { subtask in
    ChildView(subtask: subtask)
}
```

Comment: Hmm... changing it to `$subtask` results in two new errors: `Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Binding<[Subtask]>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'` and then `Unable to infer type of a closure parameter '$subtask' in the current context`. I've never seen a `$` on the iteration value in a `ForEach`. 

Comment: @CliftonLabrum It works in Xcode 13. It's called [element binding syntax](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/bindable-swiftui-list-elements/#xcode-s-new-element-binding-syntax), which requires Xcode 13. Can be back-deployed to any previous iOS versions.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I’m using Xcode 13. Do I have to enable forward-looking features like this somehow? My app targets are iOS 14 and macOS 11.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum Maybe the compiler is having troubles for you, does explicitly specifying the type with `{ ($subtask: Binding<Subtask>) in` work?

Comment: It's working (without the specified type) when I build it for iOS 15. It's just not working for the Mac version of my app, so I must have a separate issue. Thanks for your help!